# Get total count of list in Terraform

Tags: list, interpolation, terraform

I am wondering if it's possible to get the total count of a list in terraform, I've looked at the tf website and don't see anything for the total count just the use of count.index.

An example list

```
var "testList"
type = "list"

default [
{
  type = "test1"
},
{
  type = "test2"
}
]
```

So here I want to get 2 as the total count of testlist

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use terraform built-in function `length()` to get the count.

```
count = "${length(var.testList)}"
```

For details, please go through terraform documents:

[terraform length list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#length-list-)

Comment: The terraform interpolation documentation is almost always open in a tab on my work machines.